# Is there a way to make runningvalue() work in the opposite direction?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to get a running total of values, but I would like the values to go in reverse - so the start value is at the bottom and the running total at the top of my table. This is what I currently have

[image]

I'm using `runningValue()` currently to get my running total and it works fine, just wondering if there's a way to reverse the order so it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I've not tried but you could probably just do a SUM(Fields!MyValue.Value, "myDataset") - runningValue()

Comment: Check out the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a footer with a total value in a textbox named `TotalValue`, you could use an expression like this:

```
=ReportItems!TotalValue.Value - RunningValue(Fields!YourColumn.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```

Instead of `Fields!YourColumn.Value` you can of course use any other expression calculated from the fields of your dataset.